# Global Keyhook for 32/64 bit application 64-Bit Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to install global keyboard hook and on every DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH Notification try to subclass foreground window. I have separate exe and dll for both 64 bit and 32 bit application. I works ok if only one type (32 or 64 bit) exe and dll pair but not working for both at a time. I was not getting DLL_ATTACH_NOTIFICATION for 32 bit applications if I use 32 bit hook first and then 64 bit.Due to this i was unable to subclass 32 bit application.
sample code for DLL both for 32 and 64 bit with different name

```
`//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include <process.h>

#pragma data_seg(".HOOKDATA")//Shared data among all instances.
HHOOK g_hKbdHook = NULL;
#pragma data_seg()

#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.HOOKDATA,RWS")//linker directive

#pragma data_seg(".HOOKDATA32")//Shared data among all instances.
HHOOK g_hKbdHook32 = NULL;
#pragma data_seg()

#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.HOOKDATA32,RWS")//linker directive

HINSTANCE g_hInstance = NULL;
HINSTANCE g_hInstance32 = NULL;
HWND hwndKeyFocused = NULL;


static HWND hwndOld;
static HWND hwndFocused;
static WNDPROC oldWindowProc;

BOOL APIENTRY
DllMain(
    HANDLE hModule,
    DWORD ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
    )
{
    DWORD dw;
    int iRet;
    HWND hwnd;
    BOOL boIs32bit;
    DWORD dwProcID;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        dwProcID = GetCurrentProcessId();
        hProcess = OpenProcess(
                            PROCESS_VM_READ                 |
                            PROCESS_VM_WRITE                |
                            PROCESS_VM_OPERATION            |
                            PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD           |
                            PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,
                            FALSE,
                            dwProcID
                            );

        IsWow64Process(
                    hProcess,
                    &boIs32bit
                    );
        if (TRUE == boIs32bit)
        {
            g_hInstance32 = (HINSTANCE)hModule;;
        }
        else
        {
            g_hInstance = (HINSTANCE)hModule;
        }

        hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        oldWindowProc =(WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)HackingWndProc);
        dw = GetLastError();
        hwndOld = hwnd;
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwndOld, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)oldWindowProc );
        break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
    }

    g_hKbdHook = NULL;

    return TRUE;
}

BOOLEAN __stdcall
Init(
    )
{

    g_hKbdHook = NULL;

    g_hKbdHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, ProcessKey, g_hInstance, NULL);
    if(g_hKbdHook==NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

BOOLEAN __stdcall
Init32(
    )
{
    g_hKbdHook32 = NULL;

    g_hKbdHook32 = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, ProcessKey32, g_hInstance32, NULL);
    if(g_hKbdHook32 == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

BOOLEAN __stdcall
DeInit(
    )
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hKbdHook);
    if (NULL != g_hKbdHook32)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hKbdHook32);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK
ProcessKey(
    int ncode,
    WPARAM wparam,
    LPARAM lparam
    )
{
    return (CallNextHookEx(g_hKbdHook, ncode, wparam, lparam));//pass control to next hook in the hook chain.
}

LRESULT CALLBACK HackingWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return CallWindowProc(
                        oldWindowProc,
                        hWnd,
                        message,
                        wParam,
                        lParam
                        ); 
}

LRESULT CALLBACK
ProcessKey32(
    int ncode,
    WPARAM wparam,
    LPARAM lparam
    )
{
    return (CallNextHookEx(g_hKbdHook32, ncode, wparam, lparam));//pass control to next hook in the hook chain.
}
```

`enter code here`

`

Comment: The MSDN says that `The 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs must have different names`, is it the case for you ?

Comment: Yes I have given different names to both 32 and 64 bit DLL

Comment: You should also take into acccount that setting a global keyboard hook doesn't mean that a DLL will be loaded. If you set a hook from 64-bit, 32-bit applications will also be hooked, but the DLL won't be loaded. I'm not sure this is a problem in your case, though.

Comment: Also, there isn't enough information (for me at least) to tell where is the problem, try to provide more details, maybe some code you aren't sure of. Are you sure you properly set the 64->64 and 32->32 hooks ? Also, do you handle the hooks correctly in both ? If one blocks the hooks, it could explain your problem.

Comment: I think you should clean your code, because you differentiate 32-bit and 64-bit parts when you actually don't need to. Just compiling in x86 or x64 will switch all the API between their 32-bit and 64-bit versions, so you don't need to do it yourself. If you look closely, your code is strictly identical for your 64 and 32-bit versions, the only differences are those you introduced yourself. Also, you don't need the shared data : `CallNextHookEx` ignore the 1st parameter, so you should just pass NULL . Regarding your problem, I will try to launch this later and will come back to you.

Comment: thanks for the reply. waiting for answer.

Comment: I tried this and I could reproduce the problem. This certainly has to do with the fact that this hook isn't obligated to use injection. When omitting the message loops, all the injections work correctly (but many things freeze, obviously). Both 32-bits and 64-bits hooks seems to work correctly, but the first installed is called through message loop. One solution would be to do a per-thread hook (or a direct injection). You could enumerate all the existing windows or processes, filter 32-bit and 64-bit, and target `SetWindowsHookEx` on the threads.

Comment: No i can't use thread specific hook, because every time new process gets created i have to again install hook which was not expected.May be i can try to subclass windows in hook_kebd_proc and maintain flag whether sub classing done or not to avoid multiple time sub classing.

Comment: You should probably use another hook, like `WH_CBT` or `WH_CALLWNDPROC`. You will have more applications hooked, so maybe you'll have to filter, but it has better chances of working.

Comment: Yes. Also if separate hook for 32 bit and 64 bit namely mouse and keyboard will do but it's work-around